# How can you cache the conditional values within controller?

Tags: angularjs

Consider this app (http://jsfiddle.net/rQ9Za/):

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="data.type" value="1"> Type 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="data.type" value="2"> Type 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="data" ng-value="null"> None<br>

    <div ng-show="data">        
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.nested1" /> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.nested2" />
    </div>
    <pre>{{ data }}</pre>
</div>
```

The app handles the `data` model. In particular, it either nullifies it or manipulates only nested properties of a native js object. When model's `type` property gets set, it reveals another 2 sibling values (`nested1` and `nested2`) for manipulation. The problem appears when you nullify the model itself - in this case the nested values are nullified as well. I need to preserve them. As I see it, it's not a bug or anything, it's just the way it works.

Any ideas how to preserve the values over the nullification would be much appreciated.

Interesting that if I had only 2 radio options pointing the model itself `ng-model="data"` with ng-values `{}` and `null` — it would work out of the box. Here's the fiddle demonstrating the expected behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/v3bgs/

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: @Stewie, thanks for the tip. Rewrote it.

Comment: You can nullify the data object without make their child as undefined too. Maybe you need to copy to another property using angular.copy() and then make the data object null

Answer (score 1):

You can store your "type1" and "type2" in an object, and access it by the radio selection without erasing what you have typed.

Consider this :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="selection" value="type1"> Type 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="selection" value="type2"> Type 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="selection"> None<br>

    <div ng-show="data[selection]">        
        <input type="text" ng-model="data[selection].nested1" /> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="data[selection].nested2" />
    </div>

    <pre>{{ data[selection] }}</pre>

</div>
```

Dont forget to initialyze your "data" object in da controller :

```
function MyCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        type1 : {},
        type2 : {}
    };
}
```

You can check that here : http://jsfiddle.net/WCqKz/2/

Finally, you can also do that without controller by instanciate your "data" model in an ng-init directive (but I dont recommend that) :

```
<div ng-app ng-init="data = { type1 : {}, type2 : {} }">

    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="selection" value="type1"> Type 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="selection" value="type2"> Type 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="data" ng-model="selection"> None<br>

    <div ng-show="data[selection]">        
        <input type="text" ng-model="data[selection].nested1" /> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="data[selection].nested2" />
    </div>

    <pre>{{ data[selection] }}</pre>

</div>
```

See that here : http://jsfiddle.net/WCqKz/3/

Comment: Hey. Yea, this is quite close, however values must be preserved when switching between types.

Comment: But they are ! :) check the jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/WCqKz/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/WCqKz/3/)

Comment: Omg, sorry. You are right. What I meant, is that values should be preserved between types. Meaning that typing some values into inputs related to type 1, should be shared/applied to inputs related to type 2. Sorry for this confusion.